# Laravel - Display query results as singular row

Tags: laravel

I want my query results to be display as singular

I have created the Controller and the view.

Controller

```
$actives = DB::table('users')
                         ->selectRaw(' 
                                IF((plan = 1), COUNT(*), "0") as daily, 
                                IF((plan = 2), COUNT(*), "0") as weekly,
                                IF((plan = 3), COUNT(*), "0") as monthly
                         ')
                         ->groupBy('plan')  
                          ->get();
```

On the view table, the result appear as six rows and adding 0 to other rows. It suppose to be a single row and three columns.

daily | weekly  | monthly
5     | 10      | 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this with [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck):

```php
$actives = DB::table('users')
     ->selectRaw(' 
            IF((plan = 1), COUNT(*), "0") as daily, 
            IF((plan = 2), COUNT(*), "0") as weekly,
            IF((plan = 3), COUNT(*), "0") as monthly
     ')
     ->groupBy('plan')  
     ->get()
     ->pluck('daily', 'weekly', 'monthly');
```